# OpenGL code does not display anything in the window on other computers

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I wrote some code to display a shape (in this case a pentagon) in a window. The pentagon displays just fine on my computer, but when I create a zip file and send it to others to try on their computers the window still opens but the inside of the window is blank rather than displaying a pentagon as it does on my computer. Can anyone tell me why I see a pentagon in the window when I open the exe file on my computer, but others see nothing?

Here is the "main.cpp" code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include "program.h";

int main() 
{
    Program myProgram;
    myProgram.greetUser();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the "program.h" code:

```
#pragma once

class Program {
public:
    void greetUser();

private:
    char decision;
    void promptUser();
    void runOpenGL();
};
```

Here is the "program.cpp" code:

```
#include "program.h";
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Program::greetUser() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Hello. Welcome to this program test." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    promptUser();
}

void Program::promptUser() {
    cout << "Would you like to open the program? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> decision;
    cout << endl;

    if (decision == 'y' || decision == 'Y' || decision == 'Yes' || decision == 'yes') {
        cout << "Opening program...  ";
        runOpenGL();
    }
    else if (decision == 'n' || decision == 'N' || decision == 'No' || decision == 'no') {
        cout << "Okay. Exiting the program.";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Make up your mind already.";
    }
}

void Program::runOpenGL() {
    cout << "Program opened.";

    const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n" 
        "layout (location = 0 in vec3 Apos;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
        "}\0";

    const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n" 
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    FragColor = vec4(0.8f, o.3f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\n\0";

    glfwInit(); 

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 

    GLfloat vertices[] = 
    {
        -0.4f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.4f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.6f, 0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f,
        -0.6f, 0.1f, 0.0f
    };

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "H6-Project", NULL, NULL); 

    if (window == NULL) 
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        //return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);  
    gladLoadGL(); 
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800); 

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); 

    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();  
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint VAO, VBO; 

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); 

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); 

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 5); 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents(); 
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO); 
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate(); 
}
```

Comment: You absolutely do not check results of critical functions. They may fail for platform-related reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vertex and fragment shaders will not compile due to syntax errors.

Vertex shader:

<s>`layout (location = 0 in vec3 Apos;`</s>

```c
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
```

Fragment shader:

<s>`FragColor = vec4(0.8f, o.3f, 0.2f, 1.0f);`</s>

```c
FragColor = vec4(0.8f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
```

Use [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and  [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml) to check for compile errors. e.g.:

```cpp
bool CompileStatus(GLuint shader)
{
    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen);
        std::vector< char >log(logLen);
        GLsizei written;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLen, &written, log.data());
        std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return status != GL_FALSE;
}
```

```cpp
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
CompileStatus(vertexShader);
```

```cpp
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
CompileStatus(fragmentShader);
```